# Finding values of a column based on two columns values

Tags: python, pandas

Consider a dataframe

```
variable1   variable2  variable3
   a            1         w1
   b            2         w2
   c            1         w1
   e            2         w2
   f            2         w2
   g            3         w3
```

As a dummy dataframe here you can see variable2 and variable3 as a single group, it has two values of variable1 i.e 'a' and 'c' for same (1,w1).  In a bigger dataframe I want to know the combinations of variable2 and variable3 and associated variable1 values for that . Thank you for your patience. The Expected dataframe for me would be

```
variable2+variable3         variable1_Values
    (1,w1)                         a 
                                   c 
    (2,w2)                         b
                                   e
                                   f
    (3,w3)                         g
```

Comment: What is your expected output dataframe look like from this data?  Please post that dataframe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
df.groupby(['variable2','variable3'])['variable1'].agg(list)

variable2  variable3
1          w1           [a, c]
2          w2              [b]
```